# Javascript code regex replace(//g, d["$1"]) does not work as expected

Tags: javascript

```js
let data = {"phase": 32};
let title = "Phase {phase}";
consolo.log(title.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g, data["$1"]));
```

Expected: `Phase 32`

Got: `Phase undefined`

What's wrong with this code?

Expected: `Phase 32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` placeholders are interpreted by `replace` when you pass it a string as a replacement. It’s not a magical syntax-level construct that can apply the same special meaning to an expression like `data["$1"]`; just like any other function, the argument `data["$1"]` gets evaluated and only then does the result (`undefined`) get passed to `replace`.

However, in addition to a string with `$` placeholders, [`replace` also supports a replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement). You’ll need to use that instead:

```js
let data = {"phase": 32};
let title = "Phase {phase}";
console.log(title.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g, (_, key) => data[key]));
```